# Erro com o .splice, está removendo o primeiro elemento e não o especificado

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou com um problema ao tentar remover um elemento específico do `AsyncStorage`, sempre está sendo removido o **primeiro elemento**.

Adicionando elemento:

```
  async function adicionar() {
    if (produto === '') {
      alert('Informe um item antes de prosseguir!');
      return;
    }
    if (valor === '' || valor === null) {
      setValor(0);
    } else {
      try {
        let lista = {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 65536),
          produto,
          quantidade: parseInt(quantidade),
          valor: parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2).replace('.', ','),
          valorTotal: parseFloat(quantidade * valor)
            .toFixed(2)
            .replace('.', ','),
        };

        const data = (await AsyncStorage.getItem('items')) || '[]';
        let items = JSON.parse(data);
        //let items = [];
        items.push(lista);

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items)).then(() => {
          setProduto('');
          setQuantidade('');
          setValor('');
          console.log(items);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

Carregando os elementos:

```
  async function getItems() {
    try {
      const lista = await AsyncStorage.getItem('items');
      const data = JSON.parse(lista);

      let total = data.reduce(
        (acc, objeto) => acc + parseFloat(objeto.valorTotal),
        0,
      );
      let totalQtd = data.reduce(
        (acc, objeto) => acc + parseFloat(objeto.quantidade),
        0,
      );
      setTotal(total);
      setTotalQtd(totalQtd);
      setData(data);
      console.log(lista);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Removendo o elemento:

```
 async function handleDelete(index) {
    try {

      const lista = await AsyncStorage.getItem('items');
      const data = JSON.parse(lista);

      data.splice(index, 1);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
     
     getItems();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

---

```
 async function deleteItem(item) {
 try {
  var index = data.filter((item) => item.id !== id);

  console.log('produto: ' + item.produto); // retorna o nome do produto referente ao id, por exemplo macarrão, ou seja o filter está funcionando.
  
  data.splice(index, 1); // mas ainda está removendo o primeiro item da lista

  AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error: ', error);
}}
```

Comment: Qual o valor de `index`? Onde voce usa a funcao `handleDelete`, qual valor passado pra ela? Esta removendo o item anterior ao que voce deseja remover? Nao da pra entender o erro sem maiores detalhes, mas pode ser por causa do valor de `index`.

Comment: Meu caro, estou chamando a função através da FlatList, criei um botao (<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>  handleDelete(item)}>) que chama a funcao.  Pois é mando excluir um item da lista, mas remove o anterior.

Comment: Nao sei se faz a diferença, mas quando adiciona itens, o array é salvo da seguinte maneira: [{"id":15321,"produto":"arroz","quantidade":2,"valor":"3,00","valorTotal":"6,00"},{"id":16715,"produto":"feijao","quantidade":2,"valor":"1,00","valorTotal":"2,00"},{"id":39909,"produto":"macarrao","quantidade":3,"valor":"2,00","valorTotal":"6,00"}]

Comment: Adicionei primeiro o arroz, depois o feijão e por último o macarrão. Quando mando excluir o feijão, é removido o arroz.

Comment: Entendi, entao o valor de `index` seria entao, por exemplo, este objeto `{"id":16846,"produto":"arroz","quantidade":1,"valor":"2,00","valorTotal":"NaN"}`? Porque se for, vai dar erro mesmo, pois `index` tem que ser um numero.

Comment: Entao, quer dizer que estou criando array de maneira incorreta, é isto?

Comment: Meu caro, pensei que o index era o id de cada objeto.

Comment: Nao, mas se a estrutura que voce mostrou tem um `id` unico, voce poderia filtrar o items do array pelo `id` com o metodo `filter()`. Essa seria, na minha opniao, a melhor forma de remover um elemento especifico de um array.

Comment: Entendi!!! Blz, vou tentar aqui. Valeu demais!

Comment: @WanderAugusto Index (ou índice) é a posição de cada elemento no array, começando em `0`. Por exemplo, `[a, b, c, d , e, f, g]` possui respectivamente os índices `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Certo @RafaelTavares, mas ainda não entendi pq está removendo o último item adicionado na lista. Como vc disse o índice é a posição de cada elemento no array, estou tentando remover por exemplo o elemento de índice 2, que no exemplo acima se refere ao "macarrão", mas está removendo o índice 0 que é o "arroz". Conseguiu descobri o erro? Cara uma coisa tão simples que travei, tem vários dias e nada. Estudei nestes dias muito sobre array mas sem sucesso.

Comment: O @CmteCardeal já explicou que você não está passando o índice. E se um índice inválido é passado (seu caso), o [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) começará no início do array, por isso primeiro item é removido. A propósito, não entendi por que na pergunta você diz **último item** e aqui no comentário é o **primeiro item**

Comment: mal aí @RafaelTavares, escrevi errado na pergunta. Pois é o CmteCardeal orientou a usar o filter mas também não consegui. Estou revendo a maneira que criei o array.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme já foi dito nos comentários, o problema é que o [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) deve receber o índice do elemento (sua posição no array), não o elemento em si. Quando você passa um índice inválido, o `splice` começará do início do array, e por isso o primeiro elemento é removido. Por exemplo:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
arr.splice('c', 1);
console.log(arr); // ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Caso você saiba qual elemento remover, mas não saiba o índice dele, pode usar uma das seguintes funções:

- [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) para valores primitivos primitivos

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const indexC = arr.indexOf('c');
arr.splice(indexC, 1);
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'];
```

- [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para objetos

```js
const arr = [{ letra: 'a' }, { letra: 'b' }, { letra: 'c' }, { letra: 'd' }];
const indexC = arr.findIndex(objeto => objeto.letra === 'c');
arr.splice(indexC, 1);
console.log(arr); // [[{ letra: 'a' }, { letra: 'b' }, { letra: 'd' }];
```

---

Uma outra opção é fazer uso do [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), como dito nos comentários, que irá te retornar um novo array. Note que aqui além de um novo array ser criado, o array original não é modificado e **o `filter` obrigatoriamente percorrerá todos os elementos do array**.

O novo array conterá todos os elementos que passam como `true` pela condição do `filter`:

```js
const arr = [{ letra: 'a' }, { letra: 'b' }, { letra: 'c' }, { letra: 'd' }];
const resultado = arr.filter(objeto => objeto.letra !== 'c');
console.log(resultado); // [[{ letra: 'a' }, { letra: 'b' }, { letra: 'd' }];
```

---

Seu código também possui outros problemas, por exemplo;

- No `handleDelete` você não pega a lista do estado, mas sim no `AsyncStorage` novamente.
- No `handleDelete` você chama `getItems` que busca a lista atualizada no `AsyncStorage` ao invés de simplesmente atualizar os estados (você já sabe o que mudou).
- No `handleDelete` você chama de `index` e trabalha esperando receber um índice, mas chama a função passando um item do array, não o índice dele.
- No `getItems` está utilizando dois `.reduce` no mesmo array. Poderia utilizar apenas um que retornasse um objeto com os valores desejados, assim percorrendo o array uma única vez.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, me ajudou bastante, vou rever isto tudo que vc disse. Eu chamo a função getItems foi com a ideia de rerenderizar os items pois depois que excluia o valor total da lista e total da quantidade e não atualizava o estado, desta maneira achei melhor, que assim estaria forçando a atualização e rerenderiza os valores.

Comment: Você pode colocar a lógica de atualizar o estado e os totais em uma função separada que recebe a lista. Assim você chama essa função tanto dentro do `getItems` quanto dentro do `handleDelete` e não precisa ler do `AsyncStorage` novamente.

Comment: Melhor explicando: Eu chamo a função getItems, pq depois que eu exclui, não estava atualizando os estados de "valor total da lista" e também a "quantidade de items", então desta maneira achei melhor, pois assim estaria forçando a atualização e rerenderizaria estes valores.

Comment: Entendi!!!! Vou conferir esta sua ideia também, vlw!!!

Comment: Pessoal, se puderem dá mais uma conferida:
Alterei o código para:

     async function deleteItem(item) {
     try {
      var index = data.filter((item) => item.id !== id);

      console.log('produto: ' + item.produto); // retorna o nome do produto referente ao id, por exemplo macarrão, ou seja o filter está funcionando.
      
      data.splice(index, 1); // mas ainda está removendo o primeiro item da lista

      AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    }}
  

Mais alguma ideia pessoal? Obrigado.

Comment: Deixe desta maneira:  async function deleteItem(item) {
    try {
      const resultado = data.filter((item) => item.id !== item);
      console.log(resultado);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    }
  } está retornando todos elementos, parece que não está filtrando.

Comment: @WanderAugusto você precisa prestar atenção no que está fazendo. Esta resposta possui vários exemplos diferentes de como lidar com a situação. Olhe o que você está fazendo no `filter`: `(item) => item.id !== item`. Além de ter duas variáveis com o mesmo nome `item` (a recebida como parâmetro da função `deleteItem` e a do `filter`), está comparando um `id` com um objeto inteiro, não vai funcionar assim...

Comment: Consegui Rafael, obrigado pelo apoio! Fiz isto:   const lista = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('items'));

      const novaLista = lista.filter((produto) => produto.id !== item.id);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(novaLista));  ---- Agora vou refatorar, corrigir nomes de funções e alterar variáveis.